# My dev branch is 1 commit behind master after pull request

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

I have two branches: master and 0.6

I have changed some code in 0.6. I have created a Pull Request for the two commits I made on the Github website. I then merged this PR from 0.6 to master. Both branches contains the changes.

But why is my branch 0.6 now one commit behind master?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a merge between your master and 0.6 branch and the 0.6 branch to master, since 0.6 is 1 commit behind and 11 commits ahead of master.  You can review the changes diff here in the compare: https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle/compare/0.6...master

Since your repo is public, I created them for you: https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle/pull/70 and https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle/pull/71